# Quotient map of trace-zero matrices to matrices molulu constant matrices restrict to an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

Write $M_n(F)$ for the space of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$. Let $sl_n(F)=\{A\in M_n(F)|Tr(A)=0\}$ and $pgl_n(F)=M_n(F)/F\cdot I_n$. Show that the quotient map restrict to an isomorphism $sl_n(F)\rightarrow pgl_n(F)$.

My attempt:

The quotient map $\pi:M_n(F)\rightarrow pgl_n(F)=M_n(F)/F\cdot I_n$ is defined by $A\rightarrow F\cdot I_n+A$. To prove that it restrict to an isomorphism on $sl_n(F)$, is equivalent to proving it's linear and bijective. It's linear because $\pi(\alpha A+A')=F\cdot I_n +(\alpha A+A')=(F\cdot I_n+\alpha A)+(F\cdot I_n+A')=\alpha (F\cdot I_n+A)+(F\cdot I_n+A')=\alpha\pi(A)+\pi(A')$. Remains to show it is bijective i.e. injective ad surjective. It's injective because suppose it's not, then for some $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, $A'\ne A$: $I_n\lambda_A+A'=I_n\lambda_2+A\implies n\lambda_1=n\lambda_2\implies\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ a contradiction. It's surjective by definition. Hence the quotient map restrict to an isomorphism.

Comment: Do you assume that $F$ is a field of characteristic zero?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch yes but what does that mean? Don't see any implication that this is necessary?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch typo corrected, thank you

Comment: In your proof of injectivity you used that $n$ is invertible in $F$. Also, for example, the matrix $I_2$ is an element of $sl_2(F)$ if $F$ has characteristic $2$ and it is mapped to $0$ under $\pi$. In this case $\pi$ is not injective. Also note that you actually have to prove something for surjectivity, namely that every element of $pgl_n(F)$ has a trace zero matrix as representative.

Comment: But isn't the that definition of quotient group is using those trace zero matrices as representatives?

Comment: No, not really. Given a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W \subseteq V$, you can form the quotient $V/W$ and the quotient map $V \to V/W$ is surjective, yes. However, given a second subspace $W' \subseteq V$, it is absolutely not a given that the restriction of $V \to V/W$ to the map $W' \to V/W$ is surjective. (In your case $V = M_n(F)$, $W = F \cdot I_n$ and $W' = sl_n(F)$). Just think about simple examples like $V= \Bbb Q^2$ and $W = \langle (1,0) \rangle$ and compare the situations $W' = \langle (1,0) \rangle$ and $W' = \langle (0,1) \rangle$